# How are Big 5 questionnaires made to reflect adjective-derived traits?

Tags: measurement, big-five

My understanding is that the Big 5 traits are derived from the factor analysis (PCA?) of vectors of adjectives, choosing the 5 most important factors. I guess that researchers then came up with questions that are intended to reflect these groups of adjectives.

Is there more to the methodology of developing the questionnaires (Neo, IPIP) and scoring the questions other than researchers just trying to make up questions related to these groups of adjectives and then checking how these answers correlate/cluster?